# CSS Precedence and media queries

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I have `.cssClass` containing:

```
// fallback without calc
width: 60%; 
@media (max-width: 500px) { width: 58%; }
@media (max-width: 460px) { width: 55%; }
@media (max-width: 420px) { width: 50%; }
@media (max-width: 380px) { width: 45%; }
@media (max-width: 340px) { width: 40%; }
// using calc
width: -webkit-calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
width: -moz-calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
width: -ms-calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
width: -o-calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
width: calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
```

So if the browser supports `calc`, It will replace the previously defined width (60%) and It will use the `calc` approach.

However It's still using the media-queries when resizing, replacing the calc value with the queries values.

I'm getting a good result in browsers that don't support calc, because it's just ommiting all that stuff, but browsers that do support calc, obtain the calc result mixed with the fallback queries.

What should I do? I only want the media-queries to run if there's no calc support.

I'm looking for a solution or another approach without involving JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SASS will sort nested properties to have media queries last.

Here are some examples of what happens:

**SCSS**

```css
body {
    background: #000000; //black

    @media (max-width: 500px) { 
        background: #990000; //red
    }

    background: #000099; //blue

    @media (max-width: 300px) { 
        background: #009900; //green
    }
}
```

**Output CSS**

```css
body {
    background:#000;
    background:#009
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background:#900
    }
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background:#090
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urEDA/)**

What you can do is put in a second nest to manipulate the sort order:

**SCSS**

```css
body {
    background: #000000; //black

    @media (max-width: 500px) { 
        background: #990000; //red
    }


}
body {
    background: #000099; //blue

    @media (max-width: 300px) { 
        background: #009900; //green
    }
}
```

**Output CSS**

```css
body {
    background:#000
}
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background:#900
    }
}
body {
    background:#009
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    body {
        background:#090
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/urEDA/1/)**

So you can do this with your code and it should sort in the correct order:

**SCSS**

```css
.cssClass {
    // fallback without calc
    width: 60%; 
    @media (max-width: 500px) { width: 58%; }
    @media (max-width: 460px) { width: 55%; }
    @media (max-width: 420px) { width: 50%; }
    @media (max-width: 380px) { width: 45%; }
    @media (max-width: 340px) { width: 40%; }
}
.cssClass {
    // using calc
    width: -webkit-calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
    width: -moz-calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
    width: -ms-calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
    width: -o-calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
    width: calc(70% - (34px + 1.12em));
}
```

Comment: This looks to me like the `@media` rules will be placed after all the `calc()` declarations, effectively nullifying them for `(max-width: 500px)` and under. In fact, I wouldn't be surprised if this is how the OP wrote it in the first place.